# best practice for onChange in useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a child component that does a `fetch` in a `useEffect` then calls a passed in `onChange` handler. The child component gets re-rendered 3 times (and does the `fetch` 3 times) all because the parent's `onChange` function "changes".

Requiring the parent to wrap `onChange` in a `useCallback` would work but seems wrong as the parent shouldn't have to care about how the child is implemented. I could also get the child to cache `onChange` (maybe with `useRef` or a custom hook like `usePrevious`) and check in the `useEffect` if it has changed, but this also seems a little over the top.

Is there a best practice for this sort of pattern? (Ideally without requiring redux or similar)

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const Child = ({ onChange, value }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("called");
    fetch(`blah/${value}`)
      .then((result) => onChange(result))
      .catch((error) => onChange(error));
  }, [value, onChange]);

  return <div>Child</div>;
};

export default function Parent () {
  const [result, setResult] = useState();

  return (
    <div>
      {result}
      <Child 
        value={0}
        onChange={r => {
          setResult(r.toString());
        }} 
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-lederberg-opi6b9?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: fyi: https://github.com/reactjs/rfcs/blob/useevent/text/0000-useevent.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Requiring the parent to wrap `onChange` in a `useCallback` would work but
> seems wrong as the parent shouldn't have to care about how the child
> is implemented.

This isn't about a parent component *caring* about how a child component ***uses*** a passed prop or any of its implementation, it's about providing a stable reference to consumers and not triggering unnecessary rerenders. In other words, it's a performance enhancement.

React components rerender for a couple reasons, either their state or props update (*e.g. via new references*), or the parent component rerenders.

You are passing an anonymous callback function as the `onChange` prop, so any time this parent component renders, it's providing a new `onChange` function reference and will certainly trigger a child rerender.

> Is there a best practice for this sort of pattern?

Yes, memoize the callback that is passed down so it's provided as a stable reference.

Memoize an `onChange` handler function in order to provide a stable function reference to the child component so it only rerenders *to the DOM* when the `value` prop updates.

```
import { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export default function Parent () {
  const [result, setResult] = useState();

  const onChangeHandler = useCallback(r => {
    setResult(r.toString());
  }, [setResult]);

  return (
    <div>
      {result}
      <Child 
        value={0}
        onChange={onChangeHandler} 
      />
    </div>
  );
}

const Child = ({ onChange, value }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("called");
    fetch(`blah/${value}`)
      .then(onChange)
      .catch(onChange);
  }, [value, onChange]);

  return <div>Child</div>;
};
```

So now React can tell that the `onChange` reference doesn't change render to render, and so long as the `value` prop doesn't update, React can bail on child component (*and its **entire** sub-ReactTree*) rerenders *even though* the parent component rerendered. Again, this is just a performance optimization to cut down on unnecessary rerenders.

See the [useCallback hook documentation](https://react.dev/reference/react/useCallback) for further details and other reasons to memoize function references.

Comment: Thanks for the reply & example code! I understand why it happens, the main reason I dislike the Parent having to useCallback is that it's not consistently needed (e.g. Material UI components never need it afaik) and if the Child above had some sort of function like "when value changes start a download and fire onProgress every 10%" it could get into an infinite loop so it's absolutely needed in that case. It would be great if the Parent never had to know when useCallback is unnecessary/necessary.There seem to be some hooks in the pipeline that might help, useLatest/useEvent etc.

Comment: @JohnLeonard I think the general rule of thumb that if passing a function as a prop to a component you should provide it as a stable reference via the `useCallback` hook is pretty clear and trivial. You're right though, it's never a problem with rendering issues until it's a problem with rendering issues. Consistently using `useCallback` solves that issue though. Think of it as an easy way to consistently remove an entire class of render bugs.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to track value of something, you have to memoize its reference somehow. useCallback, useRef, useState, useMemo... Since on each render functions get new reference and that triggers things that tracks those functions.

> Requiring the parent to wrap onChange in a useCallback would work but
> seems wrong as the parent shouldn't have to care about how the child
> is implemented.

The parent does not care how the children will use it, it just memoizes the callback for general purpose.

Comment: Thanks for answering but what I'm getting at is I don't want to keep track of it! Ideally my useEffect would just have `value` not `onChange`. I think requiring the parent to `useCallback` is unreasonable as most other components I've seen e.g. MUI don't require it. Is the best practice a `useRef` in the child?

Comment: using useRef in children to memoize the reference of a prop is definitelly not the best practice. It is a hack. It might lead to closure problems in the future. Use it only if you know what are you doing. You can omit the callback functions from useEffect dependencies if you know what are you doing as well. Usually I put there only stuff I want to track, not the things the linter tells me. I think using ref in the children for this or not including the callback in the dependency array have literally same effect